# Bash moving files to their destination folders

Tags: bash, loops

I have folders structured like this

```
parent
|-- output
    |-- 1.Abby
    |   |-- s001_clean.log
    |   |-- s001_clean.idx
    |   |-- s002_clean.log
    |   `-- s002_clean.idx
    |-- 2.Chris
    |   |-- s001.ppt
    |   `-- s002.ppt
    |-- 3.Bobby
        |-- s001.tar.gz
        `-- s002.tar.gz
```

I would like to modify them to this

```
parent
|-- s001
    |-- 1.Abby
    |   |-- s001_clean.log
    |   `-- s001_clean.idx
    |-- 2.Chris
    |   `-- s001.ppt
    |-- 3.Bobby
    |   `-- s001.tar.gz
|-- s002
    |-- 1.Abby
    |   |-- s002_clean.log
    |   `-- s002_clean.idx
    |-- 2.Chris
    |   `-- s002.ppt
    |-- 3.Bobby
        `-- s002.tar.gz
```

So far, I've managed to create the s001/s002 and Abby/Chris/Bobby folders. 
However, when I tried to move the files inside, I only got the .log file to move to it's destination.

```
  '''
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  aa='1.A'
  bb='2.B'
  cc='3.C'


  for s in output/"$aa"/*_c*; do
    sn=${s%%_*}
    sn=${sn##*/}

    mkdir -p "${sn}"/$aa
    mkdir -p "${sn}"/$bb
    mkdir -p "${sn}"/$cc


  done
   '''
```

I don't really know how to go from here. 
How do I move the files to it's destination directory?
 

Also, is there a way that I could make the mkdir part shorter? 
I've tried several ways but they didn't work.

If anyone could help that would be awesome. 
Thank you

Comment: mkdir -p "${sn}"/{$aa,$bb,$cc}

Comment: I tried it. The result was like this：

2.childB,  |||  3.childC} ||| {1.childA, in s1  |||   {1.childA, in s2

Comment: Not needed for my answer, but try `echo mkdir s{1,2}/{$aa,$bb,$cc}` without additional quotes.

Comment: I generated testdata with `mkdir -p output/{1.A,2.B,3.C}; touch output/1.A/s{1,2}_clean.{idx,log};touch output/2.B/s{1,2}.ppt;touch output/3.C/s{1,2}.tar.gz`. You might get additional "good question" points when you add this to your question.

Answer (score 0):

With `if grep -q "$sn" "$i"` you look for `$sn` inside the file contents, not the name.
Use something like

```
if grep -q "$sn" <<< "$i";
```

or

```
if [[ $i = $sn* ]];
```

Your code will not move all files after changing this.
I would use something like

```
aa='1.childA' # original question, after edit aa=1a
while IFS=/ read -r s_output s_child s_file; do
   sn=${s_file%%_*}
   # debug echo "sn=$sn"
   while IFS=/ read -r output child file; do
      # Debug echo "sn=$sn f=$file"
      test -d "${sn}/${child}" || mkdir -p "${sn}/${child}"
      mv "output/$child/$file" "${sn}/${child}"
   done < <(find output -mindepth 2 -type f -name "${sn}*")
done < <(find output/$aa/ -name "*_*" -type f)
```

Comment: Hihi, thank you so much for your time. 
It's my bad that I used common words in the post. There are actually other folders that I want to create that are not common with the others. Could you tell me how to deal with them? thx ~

Comment: I do not understand which directories you want to create.  When you have the path of the original file split in parts you can use those parts for constructing the new path. Perhaps you want to change `mv "output/...` into `mv "$output/...`.